# mtry in Caret cross validation Random Forest method

Tags: r, random-forest, cross-validation, r-caret

I have a data frame containing 499 observations and 1412 variables. I split my data frame into train and test set and try the train set in Caret 5 fold cross validation by Random Forest method. My question is that how the cross-validation with Random Forest method chooses values of mtry? if you look at the plot, for example, why doesn't the procedure choose 30 as the statring value of mtry?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer this one needs to check the [train code](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/models/files/rf.R) for the rf model.

From the linked code it is clear that if grid search is specified caret will use `caret::var_seq` function to generate mtry.

```
mtry = caret::var_seq(p = ncol(x), 
                      classification = is.factor(y), 
                      len = len)
```

From the help for the function it can be seen that if the number of predictors is less than 500, a simple sequence of values of length len is generated between 2 and p. For larger numbers of predictors, the sequence is created using log2 steps.

so for example:

```
caret::var_seq(p = 1412, 
               classification = T, 
               len = 3)
#output
[1]    2   53 1412
```

If `len = 1` is specified the defaults from the [randomForest package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf) are used:

```
mtry = if (!is.null(y) && !is.factor(y))
       max(floor(ncol(x)/3), 1) else floor(sqrt(ncol(x)))
```

if a random search is specified then caret calculates mtry as:

```
unique(sample(1:ncol(x), size = len, replace = TRUE)
```

in other words for your case:

```
unique(sample(1:1412 , size = 3, replace = TRUE))
#output
[1] 857 181  64
```

here is an example:

```
library(caret)
#some data
z <- matrix(rnorm(100000), ncol = 1000)
colnames(z) = paste0("V", 1:1000)
#specify model evaluation
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                     number = 10,
                     repeats = 1)
#train
fit_rf <- train(V1 ~.,
            data = z,
            method = "rf",
            tuneLength = 3,
            trControl = ctrl)
fit_rf$results
#output
  mtry      RMSE   Rsquared       MAE    RMSESD RsquaredSD     MAESD
1    2 0.8030665 0.11101385 0.5889436 0.2824439 0.09644324 0.1650381
2   44 0.8146023 0.09481331 0.6014367 0.2821711 0.10082099 0.1665926
3  998 0.8420705 0.03190199 0.6375570 0.2503089 0.03205335 0.1550021
```

same mtry values as one would obtain by doing:

```
caret::var_seq(p = 999, 
               classification = F, 
               len = 3)
```

When random search is specified:

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                     number = 10,
                     repeats = 1,
                     search = "random")

fit_rf <- train(V1 ~.,
                data = z,
                method = "rf",
                tuneLength = 3,
                trControl = ctrl)
fit_rf$results
#output
  mtry      RMSE   Rsquared       MAE    RMSESD RsquaredSD      MAESD
1  350 0.8571330 0.10195986 0.6214896 0.1637944  0.1385415 0.09904165
2  826 0.8644918 0.07775553 0.6286101 0.1725390  0.1264605 0.10587076
3  855 0.8636692 0.07025535 0.6232729 0.1754164  0.1332580 0.10438083
```

or some other random numbers obtained by:

```
unique(sample(1:999 , size = 3, replace = TRUE))
```

To fix the mtry to desired values it is best to provide your own search grid. A tutorial on how to do that and much more can be found [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/tune-machine-learning-algorithms-in-r/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't understand how this var_seq function finds the values for mtry and I could not find anything in Caret documentations

Comment: @ch.elahe did you try `?caret::var_seq`. In the case of more than 500 predictors the sequence is generated using: `floor(2^seq(1, to = log(p, base = 2), length = len)`

Comment: yes I checked  ?caret::var_seq but the documentations is not complete the question is why this sequence turns out to be the best values for mtry

Comment: these are not the best values, these are just some values from min to max possible with a higher weight given the the values closer to the minimum. Best value can be determined only empirically for each data set hence I suggested providing your own values. Not 3 values but rather 10+ for a feature set of over a 1000.